How to stop a fully stuck powershell script when keyboard interrupt and `Stop-Job` not working?
The script to run used to be simply, just pin a given folder to windows quick access, like what this answer doing pintohome.
$o = new-object -com shell.application
$o.Namespace('c:\My Folder').Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")

It works well for years, but after some window upgrade, i found it will get fully stucked on windows version 10.0.19045, ps version 5.1.19041.5007.
Then i tried using Start-Job and Wait-Job to stop it after a timeout like this:
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $o = new-object -com shell.application
    $o.Namespace('c:\My Folder').Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
}

if (Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout 3) {
    Write-Output "The folder has been pinned successfully."
} else {
    Stop-Job -Job $job
    Write-Error "The operation took too long to run and has been stopped."
}

Remove-Job -Job $job

But it still stucked and even ctrl+c will not be able to stop it, i have to close the powershell window to stop.
I have tried capture the error like this and still get stucked and no output.
cmd.exe /c powershell.exe D:\scripts\test.ps1 1>D:\scripts\log.txt 2>&1

According to this discussion Pin and Unpin from Quick Access using PowerShell, it may takes a long time to run it. But i found it will not stopped even after 10 minutes.
So how can i stop it after a timeout and is it failed because windows have done some restrictions?

What happens if you do $job.ChildJobs.StopJob() in your else ?

@SantiagoSquarzon same result, got fully stucked and unable to exit

Does it also fail if instead you use $o.Namespace('c:\My Folder').Self.Verbs() | ? Name -EQ 'Pin to Quick access' | % DoIt ?

@SantiagoSquarzon try calling only $verbs = $o.Namespace('D:\TEMP').Self.Verbs() will still get stucked

put the script into a process can correctly timeout the running script, like this:
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;

$currentPath = $PSScriptRoot

$scriptBlock = {
    param($scriptPath)
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $shell.Namespace($scriptPath).Self.InvokeVerb("'pintohome'")
}.ToString()

$arguments = "-Command & {$scriptBlock} -scriptPath '$currentPath'"
$process = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList $arguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru

$timeout = 5
if (-not $process.WaitForExit($timeout * 1000)) {
    try {
        $process.Kill()
        Write-Error "Process execution timed out (${timeout}s), forcefully terminated"
        exit 1
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error occurred while terminating process: $_"
        exit 1
    }
}

